# Drawing a circle using Kinetic Js

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I'm trying to build a very basic painting application using the kinetic js framework.
All was going well up until I tried to incorporate a shape function that allows the user to click on the stage to specify a circles center points, drag and release the mouse to calculate radius then pass the variables into a constructor and output the shape.

The code I have seems to be running alright and I printed the circle object to the console and it's variables are what I expect them to be but for some reason it does not appear on my stage!

Below is my entire code. The methods concerning the circle are towards the bottom. Can anyone see why it is not appearing on the stage?!

```
 <script src="kinetic-v4.0.4.js"></script>
<script src="utils.js"></script>
<script>

    //variables
    var stage;
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var mouse;
    var startX, startY, endX, endY;
    var rad;
    var dx, dy;

    //run when the page is loaded
    function init(){

        //Create a stage object
        stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'canvas',
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            draggable: true,
            });

        //References
        //get references to elements within the body
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        //Capture the coordinates of the mouse in relation to the canvas
        mouse = utils.captureMouse(canvas);

        //Add listener to stage.
        stage.getContainer().addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
    }

    function mouseDown(){
        console.log("mousedown");
        stage.getContainer().addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
        context.beginPath();
    }

    function mouseMove(){
        console.log("mousemove");
        stage.getContainer().addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
        context.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        context.stroke();
    }

    function mouseUp(){
        console.log("mouseup");
        stage.getContainer().removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
        context.closePath();
    }

    function circle(){
        //add listeners.
        stage.getContainer().addEventListener("mousedown", getCircleStart, false);
    }

    function getCircleStart(){
        startX = mouse.x;
        startY = mouse.y;
        console.log("START POINTS: X: " + startX + " " + "Y: " + startY);
        stage.getContainer().addEventListener("mouseup", getCircleEnd, false);
    }

    function getCircleEnd(){
        endX = mouse.x;
        endY = mouse.y;
        console.log("END POINTS: X: " + endX + " " + "Y: " + endY);
        dx = endX - startX;
        dy = endY - startY;
        console.log(dx + " " + dy);
        rad = Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2);
        rad = Math.sqrt(rad);
        console.log("radius: " + rad);

        //create layer for circle
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        //draw circle
        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: startX,
            y: startY,
            radius: rad,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            visible: true
            });

        //add to layer
        layer.add(circle);
        //add layer to stage
        stage.add(layer);

        console.log(circle);
    }
```

[image: Javascript Console]

utils.js -> http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code:`circle.getParent().draw()`
That might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A JSFiddle would be nice, but at a glance it looks like you aren't redrawing your layer when you add the shape to it. Try calling layer.draw() at the bottom of the getCircleEnd method.

Comment: It seems JSFiddle is down right now, but I'll try to get one made as soon as possible to confirm my answer, if no-one else finds a solution before me!

Comment: Hey, I tried placing the .draw() function where you suggested and unfortunately it did not change anything. The Circle object was still being created just not appearing on stage... I added a screenshot of my console after I add the circle and as you can see it has an x, y and it's visible property is set to true! I have no idea whats going on!

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle please? I can't do much without your utils.js.

Comment: hey I have never used jsFiddle before, I could not figure out how to upload an external js file. So I included my utils.js code in my post above. I'm pretty new to all this so my apologies. I got the utils.js code of a developer called Paul Irish from his blog.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I have a simple script that allows the user to click and when they click it will place a circle on the stage. It seems to be a problem with the html 5 canvas. I intially had that set as my container for the stage. I created a new div called container and set that as the container and this seemed to resolve the issue...the only thing now is that I might lose functionality as I am no longer using the canvas tag..

Comment: No, that's how you should do it. That will definitely be the cause of your problem. KineticJS wants a normal div for the stage container, and then makes it's own canvas elements inside that (it creates a canvas element for each layer you create, then positions them on top of each other). Don't have any fear of losing functionality, you're on the right track now!